# 'GoogLeNet' object has no attribute 'features'

Tags: python, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, backpropagation

I am trying to use this module (https://github.com/utkuozbulak/pytorch-cnn-visualizations) to visualize what the network looks at in my images and I edited it to suit my needs a little bit. However, I get an error and I am not able to solve this problem. (AttributeError: 'GoogLeNet' object has no attribute 'features')

Initially, the module uses misc_functions.py script to process the images(get RGB, convert to grayscale, resize, etc.), but since the network I used have already done these, I edited the module a bit so that it doesn't use those functions.

Below you can find the code that I'm trying to use and the network I used to train

```
"""
Created on Thu Oct 26 11:19:58 2017

@author: Utku Ozbulak - github.com/utkuozbulak
"""
import os
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.optim as optim
from torch import nn
import torchvision
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, random_split
from torchvision.datasets import ImageFolder
from torchvision import transforms
from torchvision import models
from PIL import Image

from misc_functions import save_gradient_images

class VanillaBackprop():
    """
        Produces gradients generated with vanilla back propagation from the image
    """
    def __init__(self, model):
        self.model = model
        self.gradients = None
        # Put model in evaluation mode
        self.model.eval()
        # Hook the first layer to get the gradient
        self.hook_layers()

    def hook_layers(self):
        def hook_function(module, grad_in, grad_out):
            self.gradients = grad_in[0]

        # Register hook to the first layer
        first_layer = list(self.model.features._modules.items())[0][1]
        first_layer.register_backward_hook(hook_function)

    def generate_gradients(self, input_image, target_class):
        # Forward
        model_output = self.model(input_image)
        # Zero grads
        self.model.zero_grad()
        # Target for backprop
        one_hot_output = torch.FloatTensor(1, model_output.size()[-1]).zero_()
        one_hot_output[0][target_class] = 1
        # Backward pass
        model_output.backward(gradient=one_hot_output)
        # Convert Pytorch variable to numpy array
        # [0] to get rid of the first channel (1,3,224,224)
        gradients_as_arr = self.gradients.data.numpy()[0]
        return gradients_as_arr

#Use simple pre-trained ResNet 
net = models.googlenet(pretrained=True)

#manually replace last layer for different num_classes (necessary for pretrained models)

net.fc = torch.nn.Linear(net.fc.in_features, 4)

#to gpu
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
net = net.to(device)
net.load_state_dict(torch.load("/home/serce/scratch/titan_googlenet_epoch_100.pt")["model_state_dict"])
net.eval()

# dataLoader with transforms

tr = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((224, 224)),
    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
    transforms.RandomVerticalFlip(),
    transforms.ToTensor()
])

ds = ImageFolder('/scratch/serce/chromatin_texture/dna_sir160-163_128/sted/', transform=tr)

def get_example_params(example_index):
    """
        Gets used variables for almost all visualizations, like the image, model etc.

    Args:
        example_index (int): Image id to use from examples

    returns:
        original_image (numpy arr): Original image read from the file
        prep_img (numpy_arr): Processed image
        target_class (int): Target class for the image
        file_name_to_export (string): File name to export the visualizations
        pretrained_model(Pytorch model): Model to use for the operations
    """
    # Pick one of the examples
    img_path = ds[example_index][0]
    target_class = ds[example_index][1]
    file_name_to_export = "example{}".format(example_index)
    # Read image
    original_image = img_path
    # Process image
    prep_img = original_image
    # Define model
    pretrained_model = net
    return (original_image,
            prep_img,
            target_class,
            file_name_to_export,
            pretrained_model)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Get params
    target_example = 0 
    (original_image, prep_img, target_class, file_name_to_export, pretrained_model) =\
        get_example_params(target_example)
    # Vanilla backprop
    VBP = VanillaBackprop(pretrained_model)
    # Generate gradients
    vanilla_grads = VBP.generate_gradients(prep_img, target_class)
    # Save colored gradients
    save_gradient_images(vanilla_grads, file_name_to_export + '_Vanilla_BP_color')
    # Convert to grayscale
    grayscale_vanilla_grads = vanilla_grads
    # Save grayscale gradients
    save_gradient_images(grayscale_vanilla_grads, file_name_to_export + '_Vanilla_BP_gray')
    print('Vanilla backprop completed')
```

I don't know what the output should look like but I'm trying to get an image of the original picture and see what the neural network sees.

Comment: Are you certain `net` has `features`? BTW, it's a bad practice for a function to get input from outside its scope (`get_example_params` takes `net` defined in global scope.

Answer (score 2):

I've checked the source code of [GoogleNet](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torchvision/models/googlenet.html#googlenet) provided by torchvision.models. It doesn't have an attribute called `features`. I suppose you are finding [VGG](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torchvision/models/vgg.html#vgg11), which has `features` attributes. If you want to extract features extracted from GoogleNet, you may like to write a wrapper.

A quick example.

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torchvision.models as models

class FeatureExtractor(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(FeatureExtractor, self).__init__()
        self.net = models.googlenet(pretrained=True)
        # If you treat GooLeNet as a fixed feature extractor, disable the gradients and save some memory
        for p in self.net.parameters():
            p.requires_grad = False
        # Define which layers you are going to extract
        self.features = nn.Sequential(*list(self.net.children())[:4])

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.features(x)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    fe = FeatureExtractor()
    noise = torch.randn(1, 3, 224, 224)
    feat = fe(noise)
    #print(feat)
```